# Are Schwann cells the sole source of myelination in PNS?

Tags: neuroscience

Are Schwann cells the only source of myelin for axons in the peripheral nervous system, or are there other neuroglia or other processes that result in myelination of PNS axons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Schwann cells seem to be the most common type of glial cells outside of CNS, and **the myelinating Schwann cells are the only known source of myelin in PNS**. Other types of neuroglia in PNS, for example [non-myelinating Schwann cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC424114/) and [astrocytes-like cells](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/3/11/2206.short) do not seem to take part in myelination, neither in CNS nor in PNS.

Comment: With "seem", are you talking about what you believe, or what the medical community believes? This answer seems a bit vague.

Comment: With "seem" I mean that there is no known evidence about it in the research publications available to me. There is no way to prove that something **does not** happen, we can only prove something to happen by observing it under certain conditions (in vivo or in vitro), that is why I can't be 100% sure that this is true, but this is the common belief in neuroscience that fits into the general schema about neuroglia functions.